# Convert a UTF-8 string to/from 7-bit XML in PHP

Tags: php, html, xml, unicode, utf-8

How can UTF-8 strings (i.e. 8-bit string) be converted to/from XML-compatible 7-bit strings (i.e. printable ASCII with numeric entities)?

i.e. an `encode()` function such that:

```
encode("“£”") -> "&#8220;&#163;&#8221;"
```

`decode()` would also be useful:

```
decode("&#8220;&#163;&#8221;") -> "“£”"
```

PHP's `htmlenties()`/`html_entity_decode()` pair does not do the right thing:

```
htmlentities(html_entity_decode("&#8220;&#163;&#8221;")) ->
  "&amp;#8220;&pound;&amp;#8221;"
```

Laboriously specifying types helps a little, but still returns XML-incompatible named entities, not numeric ones:

```
htmlentities(html_entity_decode("&#8220;&#163;&#8221;", ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"), ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8") ->
  "&ldquo;&pound;&rdquo;"
```

Answer (score 7):

[`mb_encode_numericentity`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-encode-numericentity.php) does that exactly.

Comment: awesome, i didn't know that one yet :)

Comment: I think mb_encode_numericentity will do the right thing, but figuring out the right arguments is difficult.  (The hard part seems to be preserving (i.e. not converting) printable ASCII and punctuation characters. (For example, "&" needs to go to "&amp;", but "^" can stay as is.)

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a workaround, but I read a bit about `iconv()` and i don't think it'll give you numeric entities (not put to the test)

```
function decode( $string )
{
  $doc = new DOMDocument( "1.0", "UTF-8" ); 
  $doc->LoadXML( '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'."\n".'<x />', LIBXML_NOENT );
  $doc->documentElement->appendChild( $doc->createTextNode( $string ) );
  $output = $doc->saveXML( $doc );
  $output = preg_replace( '/<\?([^>]+)\?>/', '', $output ); 
  $output = str_replace( array( '<x>', '</x>' ), array( '', '' ), $output );
  return trim( $output );
}
```

This however, I have put to the test. I might do the reverse later, just don't hold your breath ;-)